# copy content in ssh Vim

Tags: vim, ssh

I need to ssh to remote machine and edit in vim. Sometimes, I need to copy some back from the 
remote machine to local machine. Is there any easy way to do it?

What I want like this:

```
remote:  select a few lines in vim, and yank it in a register or something.
local:   put the content from remote machine into a local buffer.
```

Comment: You could use `sshfs` to open all files in your local [tag:vim].

Answer (score 1):

you can open the remote file in your local vim(via scp), e.g.:

```
vim scp://youruser@remoteserver//path/to/yourfile
```